# whether the real number $\theta$ exists or not

Tags: code-request, equation-solving

I want to find the real number $\theta$, which satisfies the following two equations:
$$a_{11}+a_{12}\cos{(\pi/3)}=b_{11}\cos{\theta}+b_{12}\cos{(\theta+\pi/3)}$$

$$a_{12}\sin{(\pi/3)}=b_{11}\sin{\theta}+b_{12}\sin{(\theta+\pi/3)}$$

And $a_{11},a_{12},b_{11},b_{12}$ are some integers.

How can I solve the problem using Mathematica ？

Comment: First transform your equation with Weierstrass-substitution `\[Theta] -> 2 ArcTan[u\[Theta]]`

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as *Mathematica* code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Answer (score 3):

First transform your equation with Weierstrass-substitution `\[Theta] -> 2 ArcTan[u\[Theta]]`

```
eqn = {a11 + a12 Cos[\[Pi]/3] == b11 Cos[\[Theta]] + b12 Cos[\[Theta] + \[Pi]/3],
a12 Sin[\[Pi]/3] ==b11 Sin[\[Theta]] + b12 Sin[\[Theta] + \[Pi]/3]}
/. \[Theta] ->2 ArcTan[u\[Theta]] // TrigExpand // Simplify

(*{1/2 (2 a11 + a12 + (2 b11 (-1 + u\[Theta]^2) +b12 (-1 + 2 Sqrt[3] u\[Theta] + u\[Theta]^2))/(1 + u\[Theta]^2)) == 0, 
(Sqrt[3] a12)/2 == (Sqrt[3] b12 + 4 b11 u\[Theta] + 2 b12 u\[Theta] -Sqrt[3] b12 u\[Theta]^2)/(2 + 2 u\[Theta]^2)}*)
```

`Eliminate` evaluates the condition  for which parameters the solution exists:

```
cond=Eliminate[eqn, u\[Theta]]

(*-a12^2 + b11^2 + b11 b12 + b12^2 == a11^2 + a11 a12*)
```

`FindInstance` evaluates some of the solutions

```
FindInstance[cond, {a11, a12, b11, b12}, Integers, 5]

(*{{a11 -> 0, a12 -> 0, b11 -> 0, b12 -> 0}, 
{a11 -> 0, a12 -> -1,b11 -> -1, b12 -> 1}, 
{a11 -> 1, a12 -> 33, b11 -> -33,b12 -> 34}, 
{a11 -> 0, a12 -> 1, b11 -> 0, b12 -> -1}, 
{a11 -> 0,a12 -> 386, b11 -> -386, b12 -> 0}}*)
```

Comment: Sorry, Sin[\[Theta] + \[Pi]/3]}'s coefficient is b12, not b11

Comment: I am very sorry for that

Comment: And $a11,a12,b11,b12$ are all integers

Comment: @King.Max I modified my answer. Now it's your part to find integer solutions which satisfy the conditions evaluated by Reduce.

Comment: @King.Max Have a look at my simplified answer!

Comment: The problem boils down to solving $a_{11}^2 + a_{11} a_{12} + a_{22}^2 = b_{11}^2 + b_{11} b_{12} + b_{22}^2$ over the integers.  Since $x^2 + xy + y^2 = \frac14(x-y)^2 + \frac34(x+y)^2$, this means that we're effectively looking for an ellipse containing two integer points. It might be possible to get Mathematica to further characterize the solutions of this system using its capabilities for Diophantine equation solving;  but I played around with them a bit and I wasn't able to make serious progress.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Nice idea but  `a22->a12, b22->b12` in your condition

Comment: Whoops!  You're right, of course.

Comment: THANK YOU a lot !

Comment: You're welcome!